# ¿Como posicionar el efecto overlay sin que se salga de la clase padre?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy creando una galería de imágenes con `Bootstrap`, `HTML5` , `CSS3`, quiero dar un efecto `overlay`, el detalle que tengo y hasta donde me he quedado es que al momento de dar un `background` a la clase overlay no se ubica en la misma posición de cada imagen, y se expande por completo sin respetar el `padding`.

Adjunto mi código:

```css
#portafolio img  {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#portafolio .col-lg-4 {
  padding: 25px;
  --bs-gutter-x: 0 !important;
  --bs-gutter-y: 0 !important;
}

.galeria .cajas{
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 250px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(100, 148, 237, 0.685);
}
```

```html
<section id="portafolio">
  <h1>PORTAFOLIO</h1>
  <div class="galeria">
    <div class="row mx-auto container-portafolio">
      <div class="cajas  col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/01/09/00/adwords-793034_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen1">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cajas col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">  
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/06/18/apple-1867762_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen2">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cajas col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">  
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/06/07/53/social-3064515_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen3">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cajas col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/06/07/53/social-3064515_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen4">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cajas col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/31/22/12/phone-869669_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen5">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cajas col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/21/15/46/computer-1846056_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen6">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que posicionar el contenedor `.overlay` en el mismo lugar que está tu imagen, yo lo moví con las propiedades `top`, `bottom`, `right` y `left`, quedando así:

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  bottom: 29px;
  right: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(100, 148, 237, 0.685);
}
```

---

Como algo adicional, si quieres que aparezca el contenedor al pasar el mouse, podrías darle una transición y usando `:hover`. Aquí diseñé un poco el contenedor, lo puedes personalizar a tu gusto. Ejemplo completo:

```css
#portafolio img  {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;

}
#portafolio .col-lg-4 {
  padding: 25px;
  --bs-gutter-x: 0 !important;
  --bs-gutter-y: 0 !important;
}

.galeria .cajas{
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  top: 25px;
  bottom: 29px;
  right: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.overlay:hover {
  color: white;
  background: rgba(100, 148, 237, 0.685);
}
```

```html
<section id="portafolio">
  <h1>PORTAFOLIO</h1>
  <div class="galeria">
    <div class="row mx-auto container-portafolio">
      <div class="cajas col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/01/09/00/adwords-793034_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen1">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cajas col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">  
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/06/18/apple-1867762_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen2">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cajas col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">  
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/06/07/53/social-3064515_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen3">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cajas col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/06/07/53/social-3064515_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen4">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cajas col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/31/22/12/phone-869669_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen5">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cajas col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/21/15/46/computer-1846056_960_720.jpg" alt="imagen6">
        <div class="overlay">
          <p>Descripción</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Gracias voy a probar y comento de nuevo.

Comment: @Miguel ok estimado, me avisa si era lo que quería.

Comment: Si me sirvió era lo quería hacer, nomas que hace años ya no escribía código y hoy lo volví retomar de nuevo, de antemano gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: @Miguel un placer, saludos.